# How to continue solving? Perfect Cuboid

Tags: modular-arithmetic, logarithms, exponential-function, pythagorean-triples

I am doing research on perfect cuboids, and I'm looking for values $a,b,c$ such that the following is integer, and I'm not sure how to continue this. Any suggestions are appreciated!
$PED$ is a very large constant=$899231100768000$

$$
\begin{align}
&\exp\left(\sigma_1+\sigma_2+\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}-\ln(PED)
\right)\in\mathbb Z\\
&\sigma_1=\ln a+\ln b+\ln c\\
&\sigma_2=\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2)}{2}+\frac{\ln(b^2+c^2)}{2}+\frac{\ln(a^2+c^2)}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $mod 1$ i do not unterstand

Comment: I wrote a computer program that increments a,b, and c until it finds a remainder of 0. However, I'd like to know how to do it analytically.

Comment: I have rewritten the equations, to make it more clear whats going on. Note that I introduced the two new values $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ to make it properly fit on on the available horizontal space.

Comment: If $a\in\mathbb Z$, then $a\equiv0\pmod1$ no matter its value

Comment: @SethKitchen I guess that should do, does it look reasonable to you?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant! Thank you. Just need to solve.

Comment: $a,b,c$ are integers right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @SethKitchen You mentioned a computer program, have you found any examples?

Comment: Please don't close, it can be rewritten to something more pretty, which is an interesting problem.

Comment: No answers have been found. If one was found or if we could prove none exist we would be famous :)

Comment: Thank you for the help you have gotten me started again! If you find anything else please feel free to comment or edit your answer

Comment: @SethKitchen no answers? They're not hard to brute force, here's one $a=4,b=13,c=33,PED=1$

Comment: Wow that's awesome. Can you find one with PED=899231100768000 ?

Comment: I have opened a programming thread as well. It contains my code. It is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871148/looking-for-an-algorithm-or-help-solving-this-equation

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but too long for a comment.

Since $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\cdot\exp(b)$, the expression can be rewritten as

$$
\frac1{PED}\cdot abc\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}
$$

So we could start finding integer numerators, since the whole expression is integer when, if $n$ is the numerator, then $n|PED$, since $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, the $abc$ factor does not change whether the number is an integer, so it remains to find when the following is integer

$$
\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}
$$

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ form a pythagorean triblet, that is $\alpha^2+\beta^2=\gamma^2$ then exactly one of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is odd.

This means that at most 2 of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\sqrt{a^2+c^2},\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ are  integer.

However there are several cases where it is true that it's an integer, such as [these pairs](http://pastebin.com/XSLksMPg). This can happen because the roots left from each square root might cancel out each other. I havent been able to find any relations between these pairs either.

Comment: Haha you're actually going backward! I created this monster equation from the roots you have right now. Look up Perfect Cuboid or Euler Brick and you will understand what I mean.